# Javascript Interactjs - Delete div item on drop in dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, interactjs

Using [interactjs](https://interactjs.io/docs/) I'm trying to delete an item when being dropped in the dropzone that serves as bin. The tricky part here is that the dropzone must be in `position:fixed` and initially the draggable item is in `position:relative`. I think this causes the dropzone not to be able to detect when something is being dropped when the draggable is in a different position. I tried to fix this by changing `position:absolute` to draggable when item is being dragged(`on.dragmove`) but inevitably, the draggable overlaps the dropzone. How do I make this work?

```js
/**
* 
* 
* ineracjs
* drag and drop
* 
* 
*/
function interactJs(){

var element = document.querySelector('.draggable');

var x = 0; var y = 0

interact(element)
.resizable({
// resize from all edges and corners
edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true },

listeners: {
move (event) {
var target = event.target
var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0)
var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0)

// update the element's style
target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px'
target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px'

// translate when resizing from top or left edges
x += event.deltaRect.left
y += event.deltaRect.top

target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)'

target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '\u00D7' + Math.round(event.rect.height)
}
},
modifiers: [
// keep the edges inside the parent
interact.modifiers.restrictEdges({
outer: 'parent'
}),

// minimum size
interact.modifiers.restrictSize({
min: { width: 100, height: 50 }
})
],

inertia: true
})
.draggable({
modifiers: [
interact.modifiers.snap({
targets: [
interact.snappers.grid({ x: 30, y: 30 })
],
range: Infinity,
relativePoints: [ { x: 0, y: 0 } ]
}),
interact.modifiers.restrict({
restriction: element.parentNode,
elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 },
endOnly: true
})
],
inertia: true
})
.on('dragmove', function (event) {
x += event.dx
y += event.dy

event.target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
event.target.style.position = 'absolute';//change position to absolute to match same level position as bin?
})


/**
* 
* 
* delete
* dropzone
* 
*/
var bin = document.querySelector('.element-trash');

interact(bin)
.dropzone({
accept: '.draggable',
// Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
overlap: 0.75,
ondrop: function (event) {

$(event.target).remove();// remove from DOM

console.log(event.target);
}
})
.on('dropactivate', function (event) {
event.target.classList.add('drop-activated')
})
}interactJs();
```

```css
.element-trash{
height: 100%;
color: black;
background: gold;
padding: 1%;
width: 120px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
/* padding-top: 60px; */
}
#main{
padding: 0px !important;
margin-left: 120px;
}
#main{
background-color: #eceef0;
}
#main {
transition: margin-left .5s;
height: 100% !important;
/*padding: 16px;*/
}
.draggable {
width: 10%;
min-height: 6.5em;
background-color: #29e !important;
color: white;
border-radius: 0.75em;
padding: 4%;
touch-action: none;
user-select: none;
z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--ineractjs-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>

<div class='element-trash'>Drop to delete</div>

<div id='main'>

<div class='draggable'>Drag me</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dropzone to work, you need to have all required functions that I was obviously missing in my original post. Major brain fart.

**functions**

```
ondropactivate
ondragenter
ondragleave
ondrop
ondropdeactivate
```

**working codes**

```js
/**
* 
* 
* ineracjs
* drag and drop
* 
* 
*/
var element = document.querySelector('.draggable');

var x = 0; var y = 0

interact(element)
.resizable({
// resize from all edges and corners
edges: { left: true, right: true, bottom: true, top: true },

listeners: {
move (event) {
var target = event.target
var x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0)
var y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0)

// update the element's style
target.style.width = event.rect.width + 'px'
target.style.height = event.rect.height + 'px'

// translate when resizing from top or left edges
x += event.deltaRect.left
y += event.deltaRect.top

target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px)'

target.setAttribute('data-x', x)
target.setAttribute('data-y', y)
target.textContent = Math.round(event.rect.width) + '\u00D7' + Math.round(event.rect.height)
}
},
modifiers: [
// keep the edges inside the parent
interact.modifiers.restrictEdges({
outer: 'parent'
}),

// minimum size
interact.modifiers.restrictSize({
min: { width: 100, height: 50 }
})
],

inertia: true
})
.draggable({
modifiers: [
interact.modifiers.snap({
targets: [
interact.snappers.grid({ x: 30, y: 30 })
],
range: Infinity,
relativePoints: [ { x: 0, y: 0 } ]
}),
interact.modifiers.restrict({
restriction: element.parentNode,
elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 },
endOnly: true
})
],
inertia: true
})
.on('dragmove', function (event) {
x += event.dx
y += event.dy

event.target.style.transform = 'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';
event.target.style.position = 'absolute';
event.target.style.zIndex = '2';
})
/**
* 
* 
* delete
* dropzone
* 
*/
// enable draggables to be dropped into this
interact('.dropzone').dropzone({
// only accept elements matching this CSS selector
accept: '.draggable',
// Require a 75% element overlap for a drop to be possible
overlap: 0.25,

// listen for drop related events:

ondropactivate: function (event) {
// add active dropzone feedback
event.target.classList.add('drop-active')
},
ondragenter: function (event) {
var draggableElement = event.relatedTarget
var dropzoneElement = event.target

// feedback the possibility of a drop
dropzoneElement.classList.add('drop-target')
draggableElement.classList.add('can-drop')
draggableElement.textContent = 'Dragged in'
},
ondragleave: function (event) {
// remove the drop feedback style
event.target.classList.remove('drop-target')
event.relatedTarget.classList.remove('can-drop')
event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dragged out'
},
ondrop: function (event) {
//when dropped delete
$(event.relatedTarget).remove();// remove from DOM
//event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dropped'
},
ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
// remove active dropzone feedback
event.target.classList.remove('drop-active')
event.target.classList.remove('drop-target')
}
})
```

```css
.dropzone {
  border: dashed 4px transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 10px auto 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}
.element-trash{
height: 100%;
color: black;
background: gold;
padding: 1%;
width: 120px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
overflow-x: hidden;
transition: 0.5s;
/* padding-top: 60px; */
}

.drop-active {
  border-color: #aaa;
}

.drop-target {
  background-color: #29e;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
}

.drag-drop {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 40px;
  padding: 2em 0.5em;
  margin: 1rem 0 0 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #29e;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  touch-action: none;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.drag-drop.can-drop {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #4e4;
}
.draggable {
background-color: #29e !important;
color: white;
border-radius: 0.75em;
padding: 4%;
touch-action: none;
user-select: none;
margin-left: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--ineractjs-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/interactjs/dist/interact.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropzone element-trash">Drop to delete</div>

<div id="yes-drop" class="draggable drag-drop"> Drag Me </div>
```